# Why is my string value accumulating empty spaces when inserting into SQL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql, string

I have an extensive form inserting into a SQL database and then from an admin page I request all data and have it insert back into the form on the admin page. During the original insertion into the database, this specific dropdownlist (just like the others) is inserting the selected data. But when I go to the database, just this particular cell is getting 3 to 4 empty white spaces after the selected value is inserted. This is causing the boolean comparison to respond with false when attempting to insert back into the admin's form. i.e. ("Primary" == "Primary   ") = false. So the dropdownlist is not updated.

What would be causing the SQL row to add these empty spaces? The code is identical for all the HTML dropdownlists with its code behind. And the structure of the SQL database seems identical all the way through as well.

p.s. To undo the problem I'm attempting to use .Trim() in the code behind. But this is not making a difference. It seems the SQL database adding the white space upon insertion.

Comment: what the code? what's the type of the column? what's the SQL?

Comment: "It seems the SQL database adding the white space upon insertion." Test that by executing correct SQL directly through your dbms interface instead of passing the query through code.

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Does your column thats adding whitespace happen to be a `CHAR` or `NCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`? For example if your columns datatype is `CHAR(10)` and you insert a "Hello" into it, there will always be 10 characters in that column so 5 whitespace characters will get added after "Hello". However, if you use `VARCHAR(10)`, this won't happen.

Comment: Or `NCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Umm, @smoak that's the interesting thing. It's all done as varchar(50)..I noticed that I did at least one as varchar(100). So none of them should be adding the extra chars... But you know, that's funny. Cause it IS adding chars up to 10. If 'Primary' is selected, it inserts as 'Primary   ' (with 3 empty spaces) if 'Spouse' is selected it adds 4 empty spaces...all adding to 10. I wonder if somewhere along the way I had it as char and now the database is just not updating properly..

Comment: Okie. Thanks for your help, Bro. The deal was that my LINQ to SQL thingy wasn't updated with what the SQL database field was set to. I'm assuming that I originally, accidentally, set it to char 10 and then changed it. But LINQ wasn't updated. It's fixed now. :)